# Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

Getting this Error when called from Soap UI "Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document". Below is my code for pdf generation :

Main Method from where execution of print starts:

printFolioActivity:

```
public void printFolioActivity(final FolioActivityTO folio,
            final String printerName, final MediaTray mediaTray,
            final ServiceContext context) throws ServiceException {
        // S-845164 - Changes done to use new itext library
        String fileName = " ";  
        folioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate = getTemplateBean();
        final String method = "printFolioActivity";
        logEntering(method, context);
        LOGGER.info("Print Services printFolioActivity using " + "folio : "
                + folio + "printerName : " + printerName + " mediaTray : "
                + mediaTray);
        if (!DocumentServiceUtil.isNullOrEmpty(folio)
                && !DocumentServiceUtil.isNullOrEmpty(printerName)
                && !DocumentServiceUtil.isNullOrEmpty(mediaTray)) {
            //FolioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate template = new FolioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate();
            // Calling Folio Acitivity Template to generate the pdf
            final byte[] document = folioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate
                    .generateFolioActivityDocument(folio);

            if (save_gen_pdf) {
                fileName = saveLocalService.save(
                        DocumentServiceConstant.FILE_NAME_FOLIO_ACTIVITY,
                        document);
            }

            PrintServiceFacade.getInstance().print(printerName, mediaTray,
                    document, context);
            if(Objects.nonNull(fileName)) {
                deleteFile(fileName);
            }
            logExiting(method);
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("In printFolioActivity FolioActivityTO is null or Empty OR printerName is null or Empty OR mediaTray is null or Empty");
        }
    }
```

generateFolioActivityDocument:

```
public byte[] generateFolioActivityDocument(FolioActivityTO folioActivityTO) {
    LOGGER.info("FolioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate generateFolioActivityDocument :: START");   
    FacilityServiceFacade facilityServiceFacade = getBeanFacade();
    currentDate =facilityServiceFacade.getCurrentDate();            
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(out);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
    pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(FolioActivityTemplate.PAGE_SIZE_LANDSCAPE);
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
            document.getPdfDocument().addNewPage(FolioActivityTemplate.PAGE_SIZE_LANDSCAPE));
    FolioActivityTemplate template = new FolioActivityTemplate(false);
    generateFolioActivity(pdfCanvas, document, folioActivityTO, template);
    document.close(); // throwing exception here
    totalPDFPages = 0;
    LOGGER.info("FolioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate generateFolioActivityDocument :: END");
    return ((ByteArrayOutputStream) out).toByteArray();
}
```

FolioActivityTemplate class has all the constants declared for styles,fonts.

GenerateFolioActivity:

```
public void generateFolioActivity(PdfCanvas pdfCanvas, Document document, FolioActivityTO folioActivityTO,
            FolioActivityTemplate template) {
        LOGGER.info("FolioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate generateFolioActivity :: START");
        insertTitle(pdfCanvas, folioActivityTO.getGuestInformation(), template.activityTitleStyle,
                template.packageInfoStyle);
        
        LOGGER.info("FolioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate generateFolioActivity :: END");
    }
```

insertTitle:

```
protected static void insertTitle(PdfCanvas pdfCanvas, FolioActivityGuestInformation guestInfo, Style titleStyle,
            Style packageStyle) {
        LOGGER.info("FolioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate insertTitle :: START : GuestInfo : " + guestInfo);
        drawElementFromStyle(pdfCanvas, FolioActivityTemplate.ACTIVITY_TITLE, titleStyle, 0);

        if (guestInfo == null) {
            return;
        }

        drawElementFromStyle(pdfCanvas, guestInfo.getPackageCode() + FolioActivityTemplate.TEXT_PACKAGE_CODE_SEPARATOR
                + guestInfo.getPackageCodeDescription(), packageStyle, 0);

        drawElementFromStyle(pdfCanvas,
                FolioActivityTemplate.GI_ARRIVAL_TEXT + getPackageEffectiveDate(guestInfo.getPackageDateEffectiveFrom())
                        + FolioActivityTemplate.TEXT_DATE_EFFECTIVE_SEPARATOR + FolioActivityTemplate.GI_DEPARTURE_TEXT
                        + getPackageEffectiveDate(guestInfo.getPackageDateEffectiveTo()),
                packageStyle, 1);
        LOGGER.info("FolioActivityDocumentAssemblerTemplate insertTitle :: END");
    }
```

drawElementFromStyle:

```
protected static void drawElementFromStyle(final PdfCanvas at, final String element, final Style style,
            final int offsetCount) {

        at.beginText();
        float fontSize = style.getFontSize().floatValue();
        if (!DocumentServiceUtil.isNullOrEmpty(element) && element.length() > 50 && fontSize > 17) {
            fontSize = Float.parseFloat("17.0");
        }
        at.setFontAndSize(style.getFontType(), fontSize);
        if (element != null) {
            at.moveText(style.getX().floatValue(),
                    (style.getY().floatValue() - (offsetCount * style.getCapHeight().floatValue()))).showText(element);

        }
        at.endText();
    }
```

Exception:
soap:Faultsoap:ServerUnexpected Error occurred : printFolioActivity : Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.<ServiceException xmlns:ns2="http://exception.service.com/" EXCEPTIONprintFolioActivity : Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.

Comment: Most likely an error in the code you did not share, in particular the class `FolioActivityTemplate` and the method `generateFolioActivity`. Furthermore, please also share the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Ok, I understand why you did not originally want to post all that code. It really is too much, and there still is stuff missing. Have you tried reducing your code step by step until  the error does not occur anymore? E.g. adding only the title in `generateFolioActivity`? Also I don't see that `createFolioActivityDynamicTable` is called from you base code or from `generateFolioActivity`.

Comment: That's great. This way we nearly have a simple enough example to analyze. Now what does `drawElementFromStyle` do?

Comment: `Its just print the text with specific font and style` - looking at the code you have a `PdfFont` instance in that style. If you don't create a new instance of that object, we may have found the cause.

Comment: `at.setFontAndSize(style.getFontType(), fontSize);`

Comment: what need to be changed here.

Comment: setFontAndSize is an inbuilt method of pdfCanvas.class. where to create new instances. Please give an example.

Comment: `setFontAndSize` as first parameter expects a `PdfFont` instance. Thus, your `Style style` for `getFontType()` returns a `PdfFont` instance. Looking from top to bottom in your code, `template.activityTitleStyle` and `template.packageInfoStyle` (for a `FolioActivityTemplate template`) both are used as that parameter `style`. If the same `PdfFont` instance is used in multiple documents, this may well cause the error at hand. But it needn't have been the font, it may also have been something else, a concrete complex PDF object used for multiple documents.

Comment: What has changed in your code since the last version that worked?

Comment: It was migrated form itext 1.5 to 1.7.1 many months ago by other developer. Iam not sure from when this issue is coming and due to which change.

Comment: Ok. From the code alone I only see the `PdfFont` objects as being potentially used across documents. To check this hypothesis could you replace `at.setFontAndSize(style.getFontType(), fontSize)` by `at.setFontAndSize(com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(), fontSize)` for a test? If in that test run the error does not occur anymore, my hypothesis is correct and you have to dig into your code to determine where and when the object returned by `style.getFontType()` is created and used.

Comment: If the error still comes up in that test run, though, I have no idea anymore. I'd then need your code reduced to a self-contained code block (still causing that error) to be able to reproduce and analyze the issue here.

Comment: That doesn't work. will this issue resolve if itext is migrated to any higher versions?

Comment: As mentioned above, if that test doesn't work, then I need enough code to reproduce and analyze the issue. As all occurrences of such problems I've seen yet were due to what the error says (an object stored to one document was used in another one as if it was in there), it's unlikely an iText upgrade will help. Nonetheless, it's of course best to work with a current iText version.

Comment: but iam printing only one document here and its working fine for the first time when application started but from 2nd time throwing this error. I will try to trace the exact piece of code causing issue.

Comment: *"but iam printing only one document here and its working fine for the first time when application started but from 2nd time throwing this error."* - This is the typical issue when adding some complex PDF object to multiple documents. As mentioned above, it could be a font, but it also could be an image or something else.